# MySql Update query without where clause vs with where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to reset some values in a large table having around 4 million records.

I just wanted to know which approach is better:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET VAL1=0, VAL2=0, VAL3=0;
```

or

```
foreach ( $catIds as $catId )
    execUpdate("UPDATE TABLENAME SET VAL1=0, VAL2=0, VAL3=0 WHERE CAT_ID='".$catId."';");
```

So the actual question is that is it safe to run it all at-once or the update should be broken into chunks?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update should be broken into chunks. You can create **partitions** of the table. This way the execution is much more faster then direct query.

Answer (score 3):

```
1 - Backup your database
2 - Use the WHERE clause with update broken into chunks 
3 - increase you max_execution_time and for memory_limit values
```